# Is it possible to validate single route parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, class-validator

Let's say I have following route:

```
companies/{companyId}/departments/{departmentId}/employees
```

Is it possible to validate both resources ids (`companyId`, `departmentId`) separately? I've tried following but it's not working.

```
class ResourceId {
  @IsNumberString()
  @StringNumberRange(...) // my custom validator
  id: number;
}

@Get(':companyId/departments/:departmentId/employees')
getEmployees(
  @Param('companyId') companyId: ResourceId,
  @Param('departmentId') departmentId: ResourceId,
) {}
```

I have multiple cases when there is more than one parameter in the single route. I would not like to create separate validation class for every route. Is there a way to handle this problem in a different way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have a plain string here. For the validation with `class-validator` to work, you must instantiate a class, in your case `ResourceId`. The built-in `ValidationPipe` expects the value to be `{id: '123'}` instead `'123'` to be able to transform it automatically. But you can easily create your own validation pipe, that does this extra transformation.

```
export class ParamValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
  async transform(value, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    if (metadata.type === 'param') {
      // This is the relevant part: value -> { id: value }
      const valueInstance = plainToClass(metadata.metatype, { id: value });
      const validationErrors = await validate(valueInstance);
      if (validationErrors.length > 0) {
        throw new BadRequestException(validationErrors, 'Invalid route param');
      }
      return valueInstance;
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

You can then use it on your controller:

```
@UsePipes(ParamValidationPipe)
@Get(':companyId/departments/:departmentId/employees')
getEmployees(
  @Param('companyId') companyId: ResourceId,
  @Param('departmentId') departmentId: ResourceId,
) {
  return `id1: ${companyId.id}, id2: ${departmentId.id}`;
}
```

Comment: You can also use [class-transformer-validator](https://github.com/19majkel94/class-transformer-validator) to do all the transformation, validation and checking the error list steps in one call :)

Comment: Good point. :-) I'm not gonna change my answer because adding the notes about installing another package would make it even longer, but I think it's a very useful comment.

Answer (score 11):

As of 2022, NestJS docs say that it's possible to validate route params using the built-in validation pipe.

In a controller:

```
@Get(':id')
findOne(@Param() params: FindOneParams) {
  return 'This action returns a user';
}
```

Validation class:

```
import { IsNumberString } from 'class-validator';

export class FindOneParams {
  @IsNumberString()
  id: number;
}
```

Ref: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#auto-validation

Comment: Has this been proved to work? As of Nestjs 8.4.4 with globally installed  `ValidationPipe({ transform: true, whitelist: true, }`, the parameter is not being validated to be a numeric string